# Tufte RMarkdown Document - Self Contained Option?

Tags: r-markdown, tufte

I would like to distribute the HTML variant for the theme to be a self-contained HTML file.  Is that possible?  The following YAML header built the gorgeous file, but appears to have dependencies via the form of cache and files folders.

```
---
title: "Tufte Handout"
subtitle: "An implementation in R Markdown"
author: "JJ Allaire and Yihui Xie"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  tufte::tufte_html: 
    self_contained: true
---
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may not be looking closely enough at this, or looking from the wrong angle:

- *Self-contained* asks for just that;
- what your question notes are *cache files*

which are "merely" used to produced said self-contained file more easily.

Should work for tufte, [tint](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/tint) and everything else running through the same machinery.

Comment: Got it, so I guess my question would be related to the ability to auto-remove those artifacts.  When i use self-contained with other templates, or just base RMD, I do not believe that the assets created as part of the construction process are left hanging around.

Comment: That would be controlled by the knitr option for caching.

Comment: I am a dummy, I wasn't looking at the chunks within the example document.  Thanks.

Comment: No worries. I usually feel the same when confronted with the onslaught of knitr, (r)markdown, ... documentation.